# Todo app: getting todo-items in and out of localstorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I was trying to get a todo-app to work from localstorage, but don't quite get how it's done.
The app works through a Vue.js project with a main.js file where it is linked together from two Classes: App.js and Todo.js (watch below).

```
import App from "./classes/App.js";
const app = new App();
```

Here's a list of my findings:

1. I can only get one of my added todo's into my storage?
2. I don't seem to be able to return it from my storage? and also when I reload the page it's not
   getting loaded.

Thank you all ahead of time, it would mean a lot if I got to understand this!

I'll add my CodeSandbox link, since that will be more uncluttered to look at.
[Link to my CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-lucy-yeqs29?file=/classes/Todo.js:0-1053)

And here's the two js files anyway:
**App.js**

```
import Todo from "./Todo.js";

export default class App {
  constructor() {
    console.log("");
    this.setupEventListeners();
    this.loadFromStorage();
  }

  setupEventListeners() {
    console.log("");
    document
      .querySelector("#add-item-text")
      .addEventListener("keyup", this.createItem.bind(this));
  }

  createItem(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      console.log("");
      let inputText = document.querySelector("#add-item-text").value;
      let todo = new Todo(inputText);
      todo.add();
      todo.saveToStorage();
      this.reset();
    }
  }

  loadFromStorage() {
    const ref = localStorage.getItem("todo");
    if (ref) {
      todo = JSON.parse(ref);
    }
  }

  reset() {
    document.querySelector("#add-item-text").value = "";
  }
}
```

**Todo.js**

```
    export default class Todo {
  constructor(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  createElement() {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = this.title;

    if (li.innerHTML.includes("high:")) {
      li.classList.add("prior-high");
    } else if (li.innerHTML.includes("medium:")) {
      li.classList.add("prior-medium");
    } else if (li.innerHTML.includes("low:")) {
      li.classList.add("prior-low");
    } else {
      li.classList.add("prior-medium");
    }

    li.addEventListener("click", this.markDone);
    return li;
  }

  markDone(e) {
    if (document.querySelector("li").classList.contains("done")) {
      document.querySelector("li").remove();
      window.localStorage.removeItem("li");
    } else {
      document.querySelector("li").classList.add("done");
    }
  }

  add() {
    let todo = this.createElement();
    document.querySelector("#todo-list").appendChild(todo);
  }

  saveToStorage() {
    let myStorage = window.localStorage;

    myStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(this.title));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `myStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(this.title))`, you're saving only the title in localStorage at key `"todo"`. If you later call that same line of code again, you'll be overwriting the value.

If you're saving TODO item titles, they will all need their own key:

`myStorage.setItem("todo-key1", todo1.title)`

Of you could save them all as a collection:

`myStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([todo1.title, todo2.title]))`

but then adding a new todo involves reading the existing value before setting it:

```
myStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(myStorage.getItem("todos")).push(newTitle)))
```

Helper functions can make this all easier to read and cleaner of course.